# Can body size limit be disabled in minor fixes to existing answers?

Tags: discussion, bug, suggested-edits, character-limit

I have noticed that trying to fix a broken link in an existing answer will trigger a `Body must be at least 30 characters; you entered 16` error message.

For example in order to fix the broken link in [Emacs dired: too much information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115465/emacs-dired-too-much-information/4115699#4115699), I had to to change `Try [DiredDetails][1]` to  `Try the emacs wiki page [DiredDetails][1]` to correct the link.

If the system cannot detect such issues and allow them what guidance is there for such instances? Perhaps just add a note in the answer the broken link was fixed?

Comment: And that's why link-only answers are not real answers. The problem can be solved by deleting it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That answer is a textbook [Not An Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) and should be flagged as such, and deleted (Martijn Pieters ♦ just did so). We're grateful that you dug up the correct link, but this only solves the problem until the *next* time the link breaks.

The answer got so many upvotes because it was posted during a time when such answers weren't frowned upon; right now, if you try to post an answer like that, it will *automatically* be converted into a comment.

So, bottom line: the character limit is there for a reason and it should stay that way.

Comment: Link only answers weren't acceptable even in 2010.

Comment: @Servy well, it looks like they *were* to the upvoters. I must say I'm surprised by the amount of upvotes it got [in recent times](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4115699/timeline).

Comment: Lots of homework dump questions, link only answers, opinion based questions, tool requests, and all sorts of other inappropriate content get upvotes, even today, despite the fact that they're against the rules,   That post got upvotes because people upvoted it *despite it violating the rules*, not because the rules were any different at the time.

Comment: This answer doesn't really explain what to do when there's a good answer with a broken link. Should we simply comment the new link?

Comment: @lucidbrot true, because that wasn't asked by the OP. If there's a good answer with a broken link, please suggest an edit to the post; the comment might not be noticed.

Comment: @Glorfindel Oh, my bad, I misread the question as being about the minimal  number of characters that must be changed to be an edit. Nevermind. (I just realized that a moved link probably has enough different characters)

Answer (score 3):

> *"While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes."*

--Every single LQP reviewer that would have come across that answer.

Fixing broken links is fine, but only as long as the answer can stand on its own without them.